# How could I validate the insert button if the user did not choose a file to upload?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am developing an activity that allows the user to upload an image to firebase storage and it works correctly. However, I want to validate the user input when user did not choose a file to upload, I made a Toast message but when I clicked the button without choosing the file, the application is stopped and shows this error in logcat (see the picture)

[image: the error],

Anyone who knows the error?
Here is my method to upload the file

```
  mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            UploadFile();
       }
   });

 private void OpenFileChooser(){
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode== PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data !=null && data.getData() != null){
        mImageUri=data.getData();
        Picasso.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
       // mImageView.setImageURI(mImageUri);
    }
}
private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver CR=getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(CR.getType(uri));
}
private void UploadFile(){
   if(mImageView !=null){
    StorageReference fileRefrence= mStorageref.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
            +"."+ getFileExtension(mImageUri));
    fileRefrence.putFile(mImageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                        }
                    },3000);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Upload Successfull ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Upload upload = new Upload(mEdittxtfilename.getText().toString().trim(),
                            taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(),Title.getText().toString().trim(),Content.getText().toString().trim(),edittxtDate.getText().toString().trim(),edittxtTime.getText().toString().trim()
                            ,edittxtExpDate.getText().toString().trim(),edittxtexptime.getText().toString().trim(),location.getSelectedItem().toString(),typeof.getSelectedItem().toString(),status.getText().toString().trim());
                    String uploadid= mDatabaseref.push().getKey();
                    mDatabaseref.child(uploadid).setValue(upload);

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress= (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                    mProgressBar.setProgress((int)progress);
                }
            });
   }else  if(mImageView==null){

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No file Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If image not selected then mImageUri will be null then check is it null or not before uploading.

Replace

> if(mImageView !=null) {

With:

> if(mImageUri !=null) {

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

if image is not selected , from picker , so your mImageUri will be null.

Check for its null value , before proceeding to image upload to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Uri should be null if the image has not been picked.

Answer (score 0):

this crash is coming because while calling your **getFileExtension(Uri uri)** method, you are passing argument uri is null.

To achieve your purpose, you need to check **imageuri==null** instead of **if(mImageView==null)**